# Definite integral of cosine times a quotient of two quartic polynomials

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

If $f(x)=\frac{\left(x^2+x+1\right)^2+\left(x^4+x^2+1\right)}{\left(x^2+x+1\right)^2-\left(x^4+x^2+1\right)}$,then find $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos x\cdot f(x)dx$

Let $I=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos x\cdot f(x)dx=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos x\cdot\frac{\left(x^2+x+1\right)^2+\left(x^4+x^2+1\right)}{\left(x^2+x+1\right)^2-\left(x^4+x^2+1\right)}dx$
$I=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\cos x\cdot\frac{\left(x^2-x+1\right)^2+\left(x^4+x^2+1\right)}{\left(x^2-x+1\right)^2-\left(x^4+x^2+1\right)}dx$

But there seems no way for simplification,Please help me in solving this integral.

Comment: $$x^4+x^2+1=(x^2+1)^2-x^2=(x^2+x+1)(x^2-x+1).$$

Comment: Then $$\int_a^b f(x)\ dx=\int_a^b f(a+b-x)\ dx$$

Comment: Or another way of seeing the factorisation is $x^6-1=(x^2-1)(x^4+x^2+1)=(x^3+1)(x^3-1)=(x+1)(x^2-x+1)(x-1)(x^2+x+1)$

Comment: I got it,thank you folks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f$ simplifies to $f(x)=x+1/x$, so
$$
\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos(x)f(x)\,dx
$$
diverges.

**Addition**

This addition was asked for in a comment. The integrals
$$
\int_{-\pi}^0 (x+1/x)\cos x\,dx\quad\text{and}\quad \int_0^{\pi}(x+1/x)\cos x\,dx
$$
both diverges. To see this, we note that $x+1/x\approx 1/x$ and $\cos x\approx 1$ as $x\approx 0$ (you should make this more precise using a comparison theorem as it is stated in your book), so your function behaves like $1/x$ when $x\approx 0$. Since, for any $a>0$, the integrals
$$
\int_{-a}^0\frac{1}{x}\,dx\quad\text{and}\quad\int_0^a\frac{1}{x}\,dx
$$
both diverges, the integrals under inspection diverge.

Comment: It was given in the domain that $ x \in R-{0}$.

Comment: What is then meant by the integral from $-\pi$ to $\pi$? Also, it does not matter since $\int_{-\pi}^0$ and $\int_0^{\pi}$ diverges separately...

Comment: You mean it will not be calculated $0$?

Comment: Indeed, the integral is not zero, since it diverges. (Indeed the function is odd. But to conclude that the integral over the symmetric interval is zero, one would first have to be sure that it converges. This one does not.)

Comment: Then excluding zero out of the domain is useless,if limits of integration are from $-\pi$ to $\pi?$

Comment: Yes, see my first comment to this answer.

Comment: How will $\int_{-\pi}^{0}$ and $\int_{0}^{\pi}$ diverge seperately,can you please elaborate somewhat,i had difficulty in understanding.